# plsql code to Split Email and moblie number

Tags: email, plsql, sms

I need code to split email and mobile number that is stored in single column and store it two collection variable to send sms and email. Note that Both email and mobile number will be combined and stored in single column/variable separated by comma

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried so far? And how does the column value exactly look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated code to display both mail and mobile numbers.

```
DECLARE
  l_str VARCHAR(150) := 'adsf@qewr.com, uiohljkh@uiyhjn.com, +7(800)800-80-80, +7(900)900-90-90'; 
  l_pattern_email VARCHAR(500) := '[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}';
  l_pattern_phone VARCHAR(500) := '+[0-9]\([0-9]{3}\)([0-9]{3})-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}';
  TYPE tp_emails_col_typ IS TABLE OF VARCHAR(100);
  TYPE tp_phone_col_typ IS TABLE OF VARCHAR(100);
  l_emails_col tp_emails_col_typ;
  l_phone_col tp_phone_col_typ;
BEGIN
    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( l_str, l_pattern_email, 1, LEVEL ) BULK COLLECT INTO l_emails_col
      FROM (
          SELECT l_str FROM dual
      )
      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(l_str, l_pattern_email);  

     IF l_emails_col.count > 0 THEN
         FOR idx IN l_emails_col.first..l_emails_col.last LOOP
             dbms_output.put_line( l_emails_col(idx) );
         END LOOP;
     END IF;

  SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( l_str, l_pattern_phone, 1, LEVEL ) BULK COLLECT INTO l_phone_col
    FROM (
      SELECT l_str FROM dual
    )
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(l_str, l_pattern_phone);  

   IF l_phone_col.count > 0 THEN
     FOR idx IN l_phone_col.first..l_phone_col.last LOOP
       dbms_output.put_line( l_phone_col(idx) );
     END LOOP;
   END IF;

END;
```

Comment: Only mobile no is displayed.